# Unity, How to make Two colliders, don't collide, but still be able of interact with each others

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing a game with unity3d (2019.3 version).
My problem actually, is that I don't know how to make two colliders don't collide with each other, but still be able to interact.

Okay, let's have an example. 
Let's say that I have a zombie and a player, I want the player going through the zombie, but i want the collider of the player able of being detected by the one on the zombie, so the the zombie can attack the player, same for the bullets that the player shoot on the player. (little precision, the zombie attack the player thanks to a trigger collider in front of him).

I've already tried to modify things in the layer collision matrix, but the player and zombie aren't able to interact. So that's not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the colliders to detect eachother but not collide then you should probably set one of the colliders to be a trigger.

[image: Collider component in editor]

Just check the `Is Trigger` checkbox and that should help you achieve the desired result.

Comment: yeah, but if I do this, player and zombies are going trough the ground too

Comment: In that case you would need another set of colliders on the objects. One set of colliders for detecting the interaction between payer and zombies and another set of colliders to detect the collision between player/zombies and ground. Then you need to change the layers of those colliders and adjust the collision matrix to suit your needs.